# macos OS X equivalent of Linux .desktop file

Tags: macos, shell, shortcut-file, osx-tiger

I have developed a set of shell scripts that work on Windows and Linux and would like to distribute them for macos 10.4 and following. (They are to help language development workers in minority languages keep their software up-to-date. You can read about the project at [lingtransoft LangTran](http://lingtransoft.info/apps/langtran).)

I make the Windows installer with Inno Setup and the .deb file for Linux with [EPM](https://www.msweet.org/epm/). I have been able to make a .pkg installer by running EPM on a Mac, and it installs the shell scripts to the right place, and they work properly when I run them from a Terminal window, but I would like to provide clickable icons. If I can work out the macos/OS X equivalent of a Linux .desktop file, I should be able to get the EPM package maker to install the launcher files in the right place.

For Linux, EPM will package my hand-crafted .desktop files and install them in the right place for them to appear in the menu. (Here is one of the .desktop files:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=LangTranUpdate
X-GNOME-FullName=LangTran Update Script
GenericName=Software Distribution System updater
Comment=For updating a local software repository
Path=/usr/local/langtran
Exec=/usr/local/langtran/LangTranUpdate.sh
Icon=/usr/local/langtran/Progs/LangTran-icon.ico
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Network
StartupWMClass=gpodder
```

)
The script needs to run in the folder /usr/local/langtran because it looks for other files in the same place, so the "Path" key is set to that. The Windows shortcut files work the same way.

Since macos doesn't have a START button to open a menu tree, I would like the installer to put clickable objects on the desktop so the user can drag them to the Dock if desired.

So my question is: How do I make the macos/OSX equivalent of a Linux .desktop file or a Windows shortcut?

Comment: You are probably looking for bookmarks: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW10

Comment: Thanks, I'll look that up.